# How to find href from all tags in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I want to extract the href from all of the tags in some HTML using Nokogiri.

If I have HTML:

```
<div>
<a href="/test"></a>
</div>
<link href="/test2"></link>
<map href="/test3"></map>
```

How should do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this XPath: `//@href` to get all the `href` attributes.

Example:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(html_source)
links = html.xpath('//@href').map(&:value)
# => ["/test", "/test2", "/test3"]
```